# Removing rows from csv with powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, find, row

I have a script to remove a row from csv file if it a certain column matches a set of data.  The script works fine but I dont like it having to call a txt file to get the data it is looking for.  Here is the code:

```
$ToRemove= Get-Content c:\csvtest\SchoolsToRemove.txt

Import-Csv c:\csvTest\NEWSTUEXPORT.csv `
 |  ? { $ToRemove -notcontains $_."Schoolid" } `
 | Export-Csv c:\csvtest\ExportofNONsiffSchool.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Here is the data it is looking for from the txt file

```
7
11
27
33
37
45
42
```

How can I set those numbers in the script because they will not change.  I have tried an array but must be formatting it wrong because it always errors.

Advise it greatly appreciated!

Comment: An array should work. Show us how you're creating it, and what error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array like @mjolinor suggested. That's what the `Get-Content` cmdlet does for you when it reads a multiline-file.

See [about_Arrays](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847882.aspx) to learn more about arrays in PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I was formatting it wrong [].  I appreciate the help.  I'm so new at powershell I'm still making the simplest mistakes.